# Syntax required to improve a formula using lua

Tags: lua

I have a question regarding a volume calculation formula. We use **Lua formulae** embedded in pharmacy labels. One enables us to calculate the volume of drug from the entered dose where we use either `%0`, `%1`, or `%2`, depending on the drug, to calc to the required number of decimal places, . However even if we have defined `%2` for a particular label design/drug, for some doses if the result obtained ends up as `.00`, for best practice it is best not to show the trailing zeroes, is there a line we can add to the formula so that the trailing zeroes are not shown

## lua

```
Dose = Label.TextFromTag("Dose")
Concentration =  Label.TextFromTag("CONC")

volume = string.format("%.2f", Dose / Concentration) 

return volume
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing zeros explicitly with

```
return (volume:gsub("0+$",""))
```

Use this only if the format is *not* `%.0f`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, I was tried to avoid getting tripped by things like `1000`. Your solution does not simplify `1.20` to `1.2`. Perhaps this is what the OP wants, I don't know.

Comment: Sorry.  That should be `:gsub("(%.%d-)0+$", "%1"):gsub("%.$", "")` to work correctly with `1.20`